# MRTK sample build not for Hololesn 2 emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, hololens-emulator

[image: Error with IL2CPP build]
[image: Error With IL2Cpp Build]

I'm getting these errors while just building a sample scene for HoloLens 2 emulator.

Also, if I build with .net scripting back-end it builds successful but the app crashes immediately.

Comment: What video card do you have in your PC?  Are you using the latest drivers for that card from the chipset manufacturer (e.g., from nvidia.com for an NVIDIA card)?

Comment: Also, does this issue reproduce if you turn off hardware acceleration for the emulator?  (To do that, click the Tools (">>") button, go to the Optional Settings tab and uncheck the checkbox, which will prompt you to restart the emulator.)

Comment: my laptop has inbuilt graphics Intel 620,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have identified an issue with the November update that causes the issue you're seeing.  Please use the October update, which you can download from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator.  You do not need to uninstall the November update, but when targeting the emulator in Visual Studio, please set the target build to 10.0.18362.1034.

Comment: Thanks, let me me give a try to this one.

Comment: using this emulator version and switching off the hardware acceleration works for me , thank you so much.